# Unable to download purchased apps because cloud symbol missing on some apps in itunes

Tags: itunes, icloud, applications

I am usually backing all apps which I purchase. Recently I purchased a bunch of new apps, which I would like to download. So I opened the iTunes (12.6.20) switched to purchases and right now I see that cloud icon for downloading the app in some apps is missing. See picture.

Do you know what is causing this problem? I would like to download all my purchased apps. Sign off/on doesn`t solve the problem.

Thanks for the help.

Some facts:

- My local apps library is completely empty, so nothing is downloaded yet.
- I am currently using 12.6.3.6 iTunes
- If somebody else will sign into same iTunes on the same computer as I do he is able to download    all apps
- I am a family organizer for family sharing
- I tried to sign on different computers to iTunes and the apps which I can download where all same.
- The solution that I can download the app by searching this app on iTunes doesn`t help because I would like to download a purchased app  which is currently not available. (Yes It can be, My brother has the same app purchased which is not available yet but through purchases, list can be downloaded)

[image]

Comment: the cloud icon is usually just updates or something that didn't transfer to your Mac.

Comment: Ok so is there a way to download a app from purchases? Because I have nothing in local apps library in iTunes.

Comment: For example I have in purchases app which is not available in AppStore but I would like to download it.

Comment: Maybe try 12.6.3 - https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT208079

Comment: @Tetsujin nope, no changes. I tried also on different comupters and still only the same apps are available to download

Comment: you don't happen to use two different accounts on itunes, do you?

Comment: well I am using one itunes account with multiple email addresses and I am a familly organizer. I saw that when a familly memmber sign to their itunes account on my itunes they can download all apps. But when I sign in, I can download just a few of them

Comment: Apple have been [winding back the support for apps in iTunes](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8065171) recently, expecting you to kludge around with iOS instead. Perhaps the download icon is actually for the macos version, and doesn't appear for iOS only apps. I'd try App Store on macos for macos apps and App Store on iOS for iOS apps. Could be another one of Apple's recent attempts at bewildering their users.

Comment: @HeathRaftery Yes apple is winding back, but my brother was able to download every app from iTunes on my computer. I just log out and he logs in, and bum, he was able to download all apps. But then I log back and I can download only certain apps.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I would try downloading the apps onto your device with whoever a sign in shows all of them in there library and then log out of there sign in and sign back into your name and see if that helps I had a similar issue in the past and this seemed to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you authorize iTunes with your Apple ID account. When you authorize your Mac or PC, you give it permission to access your apps, audiobooks, books, music, movies, and other content.

Comment: yes, account is authorized, if not I will be unable to download all apps. But I can download some of them, but not all of them. Thats the problem

Comment: Check for an iTunes update. If yours is up to day (I think 12.7 is out) then call Apple Support. This appears to be an issue with iTunes.

Comment: Ok, i have the last official itunes which supports apps downloading.